# Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:4401/

Tags: python, node.js, git, github, dns

**Hi there**,

friends, first I want to say I'm an absolute beginner. Your help makes me so *motivated*.

I am doing one assignment. they provide templates for the front end(angular) and back end (node.js, SQLite). I want to edit some code to complete that.

**1. for the Front end**

- implement a searching functionality for the teacher and student classes

**2. for the Back end**

- Update the readStudents function to read all student data.
- Update the readStudentInfo function to read the information of a specified student.
- Update the addStudent function to add a student.
- Update the updateStudent function to update details of a specific student.
- Update the deleteStudent function to delete a specified student.

I have completed all tasks *myself*.

I use **GitHub to auto-grading** it shows *80/160*. I passed all back-end tasks but it shows **I failed all front-end tasks**.

- The task for my side is to complete (*implement a search functionality*). so think that this is their side problem or any technical error.

I add the screenshot about auto-grading and the error message.

[image]

These are a few example images of errors, if you want to see all the error screenshots you ask me for, I will add this question.

[image: .]

[image]

[image]

[image]
..

If you want to see any file of mine, **u can ask** I will add it here **so fast**.
please help me to solve this error. I am so tired to finish it. Your guide makes me move one step.

Thank you for read this :)

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with the configuration. When you run the frontend locally does it run at port `4401`?

Comment: The front-end is working but it works on port 4200