# Issue on GitHub unit testing / Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:4401/

Tags: python, node.js, git, github, dns

I am doing one web development assignment. I am using angular as a front-end framework and node, SQLite for the back-end.

My project is working fine while I am using GitHub auto-grading it shows an error.

It says my all front-end testing is failed and it shows the same error for all failed tests.

I add the screenshot below.

if you want to see any of my files you can ask.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the error message.

```
Testing Student UI
   ✖ Testing edit students
  
     1) Failed to load the page at "http://localhost:4401/student".
        Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the
        "retryTestPages" option, or use quarantine mode to perform
        additional attempts to execute this test.
        You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at
        "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
        
        Error details:
        Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at
        "http://localhost:4401/student".
```

The new error.

[image]

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. From that error, it looks like you are testing the endpoints but the server hasn't been started yet.

Comment: please visit this question. if you want to know anything ask me, and I will add it so fast.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75507138/failed-to-load-the-page-at-http-localhost4401

Comment: Is that your complete workflow? Where is the step where the server is started? If this is a public repo, please include its link in your question. That would be easier to look into.

Comment: `npm start` is missing for your backend in your workflow. Please try to match the commands in your workflow as you test locally.

Comment: I use `npm start` at first and its works. my project(back-end) is running on port 8080

Comment: I mentioned earlier. The project is working fine(front end and back end). The issue is at the unit test while GitHub auto-grading.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Ok, I will do it. If you want any details ask me I will add so fast

Comment: There is no step in your [workflow](https://github.com/OpenUOM/capstone-project-assignment-Minfaas/blob/main/.github/workflows/classroom.yml) where you run `npm start`. That's what I'm referring to. Please consider everything that you do to run tests locally and replicate the same in your GHA workflow.

Comment: See this example [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdjrFSw0AMRPv7ClV0JjDpXDBhUkBPQZFJcbaFfeQs3Zwkp+Hj8Tkmw7iTtLt6S37EGt6CvlsDx+hFMvMIn5wvX5GvzjHVcEomw9m5hHkMIoFJagfQDthepIZrDorz7ltdJMjou6IzKZL+Hdw3N0uusRC7MgBkI6kKwhojtSp6RdFFEsUkNxdABbQUPRYkm65nABOc/6/kXbvKh2m/CX6ozwqCecJ8D8/0Gn7uKwDxYAkojTO9+F9ugcfIPTz880lETLB/kg3l1ZT77Dvc9MPOWl8q7vzqCNQfpudfwF50UA==).

Comment: ah ok. I am a beginner I don't know much about it. if I use your example is it ok? will the error solve?

Comment: Hii bro, after I change the code from index.js. Port 4401 is running. I add the change code below
`
const server  = require ("./server.js");

const PORT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? 4401 : 8080;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Capstone Project Backend is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

`

The old error has gone. now I got a new error. but I think it can be solved easily. can u help me to solve it?
I will add a screenshot of the question.